# Log any command similar to `time`

Tags: bash

The `time(1)` command allows you to time any command, by passing it as arguments to `time`.

I know it's possible to redirect `stderr` and `stdout` to a file via `2>&1`, and there's also `tee(1)` which allows one to copy its input to both the screen and a file.  However, I do not know how to add timestamps to logs.

Is there a tool to redirect `stderr` and `stdout` to a file, AND append timestamps to it for logging purposes?

Comment: I read your first sentence multiple times, but it doesn't make any sense. Did you forget 'to' between 'you' and 'time'? Any reason to fumble with adding time **after** the entry in a log? Why are you not using `logger` and get a standard entry (with timestamp **before** the log entry)?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `ts(1)` from moreutils.

---

`ts` from [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) will prepend a timestamp to every line of input you give it. You can format it using strftime too.

```
$ echo 'foo bar baz' | ts
Mar 21 18:07:28 foo bar baz
$ echo 'blah blah blah' | ts '%F %T'
2012-03-21 18:07:30 blah blah blah
$
```

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

---

Contents copied from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813614/221689

Answer (score 3):

Try `annotate-output` from Debian's *devscripts* package.  It shows timestamps, and writes "O" before standard output, and "E" before standard error.  Example:

```
# run `ls` on one file that exists, and one that doesn't...
annotate-output ls /bin/bash /tmp/boosh
```

Output:

```
03:30:52 I: Started ls /bin/bash /tmp/boosh
03:30:52 O: /bin/bash
03:30:52 E: ls: cannot access '/tmp/boosh': No such file or directory
03:30:52 I: Finished with exitcode 2
```

Comment: Interesting. This does not have date stamp, am I right?

Comment: @Edward, it *does* have date stamping, just pass it a `date` string:     `annotate-output +"%D %H:%M:%S" ls /bin/bash /tmp/boosh`; see `man date` for a list of all the date string format codes.