# How do I prepend a line read from STDIN with an epoch timestamp?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, date

I'm wanting to prepend the [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to a single line of arguments. My desired output is:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | some_bash_awk_sed_date_program_or_something_else
1491146539 foo bar baz
```

The actual output I'm getting can be seen below:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | awk -f time_stamper.awk
1491146539
0 foo bar baz
```

My `time_stamper.awk`:

```
BEGIN { 
OFS=" "
printf "%s ", system("date +'%s'")
}
{ print }
```

I think the leading `0` is coming from the return value from [`date +'%s'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094354/2909897). I was expecting setting the `OFS=" "` would at least return `1491146539 0 foo bar baz` changing the newline to space.

Some questions about my current attempt:

- What is wrong with my usage of the `OFS` [built-in variable](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk-3.0.3/html_chapter/gawk_11.html)?
- Why is the `0` printing in front of `foo bar baz`?

More importantly, I'm not sure if `awk` is the right tool for the job. Maybe I should use `sed`, `date` or some other utility.

- How do I print the desired output?

Note: This question is more specific and therefore different from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331003/log-any-command-similar-to-time). Also, the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331013/173557) requires the installation of [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) which seems like an interesting addition the Unix toolset; however, I'd rather stick with more traditional Unix utilities to perform my task.

Answer (score 5):

The `system()` function in `awk` run the command and return its status. You got `0` because the command is success. The output of `date +'%s'` was printed separately.

To get the output of external command, you would use [getline()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_14):

```
$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{"date +%s" | getline d; printf "%s %s\n", d, $0}'
1491147643 foo bar baz
```

There's nothing to do with `OFS`, because it's a space by default.

---

With `gawk` or `mawk`, you can also do:

```
echo foo bar baz | gawk '{printf "%s %s\n", systime(), $0}'
```

The `systime()` return the number of seconds since epoch, not counting leap seconds

---

IOW, you can do it alone with `date`:

```
date +'%s foo bar baz'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Bash**
Here we use a `while` loop to ingest the arguments from stdin & perform NO splitting since we use `IFS=` with the `read`. This enables the entire line with the concomitant whitespace to be preserved. And finally, we `echo` the `timestamp` along with the arguments now available via the `$l` variable. A point to be kept in mind is that all arguments to `echo` need to be quoted for predictable behavior of the code.

```
echo 'foo     bar baz' | while IFS= read -r l; do echo "$(date +'%s')" "$l"; done
```

**Perl**

`-n`  option instructs `Perl` to read a file line-by-line + not to print unless specifically asked to. Each line read in is stored in the `$_` which is equivalent to `$0` of `awk`. `time()` is a `Perl` `builtin` function to give us the `epoch` time. Then we put the epoch time and the current line in an `anonymous` array reference `[ ..., ... ]` and get back the contents of this array by `dereferencing` it, `@{ ... }` The double quotes `"..."` around the `@{...}` expression ensure that the list elements shall be space separated. Then we print them.

```
echo ... |  perl -ne 'print "@{[+time,$_]}"'

IFS= read -r l <<<"$(echo 'foo    bar baz')"
printf '%d %s\n' "$(date +'%s')" "$l"
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples! Can you please provide more context/links to documentation to explain your examples?

Comment: Done.. You may check.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with sed as

**Code:**

```
 echo 1 2 3 | sed 's/^/'`date +"%s"`' /'
```

**Results:**

```
1491148928 1 2 3
```